# Is it possible to enable/disable SSH using cron

Tags: ssh, cron

I would like to disable the `ssh` server for certain times of the day. I would like to do this because I recently experienced a brute force compromise via `ssh`. Can `crontab` be used to enable/disable SSH?

If not, is there another way to disable `ssh` at certain times of the day?

Comment: Do you mean you want to control the ssh _server_? Or did you really mean control of a client?

Comment: What flavor of Unix are you wanting to do this on?

Comment: @DonSimon RHEL - But, I also have some Ubuntu servers as well.

Comment: @roaima I want to prevent bots from constantly attacking.  If SSH is only available at certain times  in the day, I can minimize the attack vector.

Comment: So you do mean you want to control the ssh _server_. I will update your question to clarify this.

Comment: See the below answer, but the real recommendation would be to set your sshd to only allow public-key access at a bare minimum.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, just run whatever init scripts there are to stop and start ssh daemon (e.g. `/etc/init.d/ssh stop` and `/etc/init.d/ssh start`) at appropriate times.

However, I'd suggest looking into fail2ban, portknocking, disabling password authentication and using only ssh keys, and the most secure way, [two factor](https://sysconfig.org.uk/two-factor-authentication-with-ssh.html) authentication with [one ti](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/otpw.html)[me passwords](http://www.howtogeek.com/121650/how-to-secure-ssh-with-google-authenticators-two-factor-authentication/).

Comment: Does this work with `systemd`, as used on RHEL, too?

Comment: @roaima No, use `systemctl [start|stop] sshd` instead

Comment: @nanny that's what I thought. So this answer won't work for the situation the OP is in?

Comment: @roaima RHEL? You can easily do `service sshd restart`

Comment: @HankyPanky good to know, but that's not what this answer offers, either. (Perhaps RadovanGarabik will update their answer to handle the more general case.)

Comment: @roaima I guess it depends on what OP is using to manage services, he could be using an old version. But your point is very valid, this answer should be updated.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of shutting down the SSH server during certain hours, consider using the [pam_time](http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_time.html) module instead to deny authentication during certain times of the week.  It's less of a hack, doesn't depend on cron, and also gives you more flexibility to define your authentication ruleset.

- Set `UsePAM yes` in your `sshd_config`
- Edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` to insert the `pam_time` module
- Write your time-restriction rules in `/etc/security/time.conf`.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of options available to you

1. You can use `cron` to switch the `ssh` server on and off
2. You can use `iptables` to block and unblock  the `ssh` port
3. You can sidestep all of this by running `ssh` on  different port
4. You can implement port knocking
5. You can disable external access to `ssh` entirely and mandate use of a VPN

I'm sure other solutions are available, but I've stopped at five.

Comment: +1 for #3. Never run ssh on port 22, always change it. That will stop almost 100% of automated attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the "fail2ban" log monitoring dæmon. It will use iptables to block access to your sshd from a specific IP address. if there are more than 5 incorrect log-ins within a few minutes. However, it is IPv4 only.

Also, disable root logins; always use a bounce account.

Comment: If it's IPv4 only I'd better tell it to stop working for my IPv6 networking layer. (`fail2ban` can be used to run pretty much _any_ command when a pattern is matches in a log file.)

Answer (score 2):

There is the `time` module for iptables:

```
iptables ... -m time --timestart TIME --timestop TIME --days DAYS -j ACTION
```

Use `-p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-rst` to pretend the port is closed (the default action for `REJECT` is an ICMP packet).

I'd also add another rule in front, allowing `ESTABLISHED` connections through if I wanted open connections to remain working.

Compared to solutions using scripting to perform certain actions at certain times it has the great advantage that this is static configuration, and there are unlikely to be any failure modes that would e.g. permanently block access.